# edit pd Dataframe through iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of Series created by pandas.read_html().

I'm trying to run drop() on each Series in each iterrow() label of the dataframe with the code below:

```js
df = pd.read_html('http://openinsider.com')
df = df[-3]
rm = ['1m', '1w', '1d', '6m']
for index, label in df.iterrows():
    print(label)
    label.drop(index=rm, inplace=True)
    label.dropna(inplace=True)
    print(label)
```

I can see the values being removed in the print statements, but the dataframe is unchanged.

Comment: Dataframe is not updated, as dropna is not called on the variable df. See [this](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/pandas/pandas-dropna-how-to-drop-missing-values/) for examples using drop, dropna.

Comment: The rows of your dataframe are returned as Series, so you get back copies that are no longer connected to the original data frame, so edits don't change your dataframe. Using the current index, you can access and edit the relevant row of the dataframe using `df.loc[]`, however this approach may be slower, instead you should explore using `apply` or `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want:

```
df = df[df.columns.difference(rm)]
print(df)

# Output:
               Company Name          Filing Date                  Insider Name     Owned    Price      Qty Ticker                  Title  Trade Date    Trade Type        Value    X   ΔOwn
0              Airbnb, Inc.  2021-12-17 21:59:52              Jordan Jeffrey D    322696  $166.25   -10000   ABNB                    Dir  2021-12-16      S - Sale  -$1,662,500  NaN    -3%
1              Airbnb, Inc.  2021-12-17 21:57:59            Johnson Belinda J.    199327  $166.25   -20000   ABNB                    Dir  2021-12-16   S - Sale+OE  -$3,325,000    D    -9%
2        Venus Concept Inc.  2021-12-17 21:45:12  Ew Healthcare Partners, L.P.  32043822    $1.25  3920000   VERO                    10%  2021-12-15  P - Purchase  +$4,900,000  NaN   +14%
3        Venus Concept Inc.  2021-12-17 21:31:06           Barry Richard Scott  16337856    $1.25  3920000   VERO               Dir, 10%  2021-12-15  P - Purchase  +$4,900,000  NaN   +32%
4  Hims & Hers Health, Inc.  2021-12-17 21:28:10                Becklund Irene     25587    $6.35    -4509   HIMS       Interim PFO, PAO  2021-12-15       F - Tax     -$28,632    D   -15%
5  Hims & Hers Health, Inc.  2021-12-17 21:27:54                  Dudum Andrew  11409129    $6.35   -22053   HIMS               CEO, 10%  2021-12-15       F - Tax    -$140,037    D     0%
6  Hims & Hers Health, Inc.  2021-12-17 21:27:36               Boughton Soleil    389715    $6.35    -5255   HIMS                     GC  2021-12-15       F - Tax     -$33,369    D    -1%
7  Hims & Hers Health, Inc.  2021-12-17 21:27:20                 Baird Melissa    257681    $6.35    -9572   HIMS                    COO  2021-12-15       F - Tax     -$60,782    D    -4%
8  Hims & Hers Health, Inc.  2021-12-17 21:26:34      Carroll Patrick Harrison     20857    $6.35    -1368   HIMS  Chief Medical Officer  2021-12-15       F - Tax      -$8,687    D    -6%
9              Ocugen, Inc.  2021-12-17 21:24:13                  Potti Manish     72695    $1.43    45000   OCGN                    Dir  2021-12-16     M - OptEx     +$64,530    D  +162%
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have column names with empty strings or nan? Or do you wan to drop any columns that contain only nan or empty strings?